# Forward traffic from a socks server to another socks server, based on some application layer "parameters" such as domain name or TLD extension

Tags: ssh, http, socks

I want to configure a socks server (with ssh dynamic port forwarding for example) who can forward the traffic to another socks server or http server maybe ... and I want this routing to happens at "application layer" : based on domain name or TLD extension for example.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best to set up squid (or another reverse proxy) and set up various SOCKS servers or HTTP servers as upstreams.